# Remove or hide time row from the kendo scheduler in angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular8

how to remove or hide the Time-Row from the Scheduler in angular 8.

here is the code with sample date in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brn2en-rtbgjt

I want to remove or hide the second row: "11:00 AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove or hide the second row: "11:00 AM"

To achieve your above requirement, you can try to apply following CSS styles to Kendo UI for Angular Scheduler.

```
div.k-scheduler-timeline-month-view>div:nth-child(1)>div.k-scheduler-times>table.k-scheduler-table tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}

div.k-scheduler-header-wrap table.k-scheduler-table tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: HI, thanks for the response.
I have applied the same css but still it is showing the second row

Comment: no it didnt work for me ... css is not getting reflected

Comment: As shown in screenshots of my test result, it works well with your provided code. If it does not work for you, you can check if above styles are overridden by other css styles using browser developer tool.

Comment: it worked after adding,   
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
in the component page. 
Thank you so much.